# Relations in Group Presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-presentation

In an introduction to abstract algebra, I was recently introduced to the idea of presenting a group - minimally, a group is just a set of generators along with a set of relations amongst the generators. I believe that I have, at least, a rather basic understanding of this idea. On the other hand, I don't quite understand when one knows that they have a sufficient amount of relations to uniquely characterize the group at hand. For example, a common example for generators and relations is the Dihedral group $ D_n = \{ \rho, \tau : \;\rho^n = 1, \tau^2 =1, \tau\rho\tau^{-1}=\rho^{-1} \}$. Clearly there are two generators here: a rotation $ \rho $ by an angle $ 2\pi/n$ and a reflection $ \tau $. What I don't understand is exactly how one knows that these three relations as listed are sufficient to characterize the group. When listing the relations, I see that each of these properties are true, but how does one know that they cannot stop with just $ \rho^n = 1$ and $ \tau^2= 1 $, the most basic properties of $D_n$? A small bit of clarification here would be greatly appreciated as I feel as though I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5):

This won't address your specific question here, but more of my general feeling about presentations.

**Key idea**: Presentations make it easy to communicate the particular group you're working with, but are generally hard to come up with, or work with!

---

For example, there are lots and lots of groups of order $96$ -- 231 of them, [to be precise](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_96). But if you've found an interesting one (say, [this guy](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7813/120540)), how in the world would you describe it to someone, especially if it doesn't belong to a fairly well-known family, or have a nice description as (semi)direct products?

That's where a presentation comes into play. Supposing you *have* such a presentation, you just write it down, tell your friend, and that's that. Your job is done!

This is ignoring the fact that it's really nontrivial to determine a set of relations that pins down your group. I've never even thought of doing this, but I'd wager it's not a pleasant task. Why would I be willing to wager that?

Let's go back to your friend, when she receives receives the compact presentation you sent earlier. She has her work cut out for her! See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1291619/120540) of mine for an idea of the kind of work required just to list elements, for a group of order only $8$. Long story short, it's completely nontrivial to actually unpack a presentation, in general. This is without even mentioning the [word problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups), which in a sense makes precise how difficult it is.

So in summation, group presentations are nice as exactly that -- presentations. If you have *any* other description of the group to work with, chances are, it'll be easier than working with the presentation.

Answer (score 2):

The relation $\tau \rho \tau ^{-1} = \rho ^{-1}$ tells you about how $\tau$ and $\rho$ interact. Without it, you would just have a free group on two letters modulo those order relations.

You can consider $D_{2*4} = D_8$ the rotations of the square and convince yourself that composing rotations and reflections does indeed satisfy such a relation.

An informal explanation now on why these three relations should be sufficient:

By the geometric argument I used in $D_8$, we should be able to convince ourselves that there is a group of order $2n$ with the relations as described in the presentation. So any such presentation gives rise to a group of order $2n$ or larger. Now I claim that the relation between $\rho$ and $\tau$ will restrict the order to at most $2n$.

The relation $\tau \rho \tau ^{-1} = \rho ^{-1}$ is usually called a commuting relation, because it tells you how to move the $\tau$ and $\rho$ between each other. With this relation, we can present every word in $D_{2n}$ as $\rho ^i \tau ^j$ where $0 \le i < n$ and $j = 0,1$. Now it is clear that indeed there can be at most $2n$.

This still goes back to what I hoped to convey originally which was that we need a third relation that tells us how the rotations and reflections behave together. I hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: The group with reations just $r^n=t^2=1$ is not abelian, and not even finite.

Comment: I think that should be the free product $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So in general, there must be a relation between each generator? I don't think you addressed the problem in general of how one knows that they have sufficient relations amongst the generators

Comment: Yes sorry, I primarily work with free abelian groups and made that assumption here.

Comment: I added additional arguments attempting to address why the three conditions should be both sufficient and necessary by expanding on what I said originally. Let me know if you would like me to clarify further.